# Video and Voice chat operability in Python

Tags: python, audio, chat, voice

I'm trying to find resources on video and voice chat operability in Python... Does anybody know of some good resources or sample projects?

Any help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something higher level you can try [Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy). It has python bindings so you can use chat GUI elements on your application or create your own. If you want something lower level, you might want to try to use [Telepathy Python](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/Telepathy%20Python) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Basically a farsight lib which has xmpp-jingle that can accomodate video and voice chat is commonly used,for python itz farsight.py: try it.....!