# How to implement a voice chat functionality using Python?

Tags: python, chat, voice

My goal is a cross-platform voice chat application. The part I am a bit confused about it's the voice transferring one : )

What can you suggest? Maybe a binding to some low-level library or even a framework?

BTW, I don't have to use Python, so if you think that Python is not a good idea for this purpose, please show me the true way : )

Comment: Take a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590053/video-and-voice-chat-operability-in-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into Telepathy:

http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/

There are Python bindings available:

http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/wiki/Telepathy%20Python

See also; the end of this presentation features an IM/Voip client in 20 lines:

http://raphael.slinckx.net/files/telepathy-guadec-2007.pdf